# Ordering a MySQL query with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two MySQL database tables: one containing a list of championships and another recording title changes. The schemas look like this:

`championships`

```
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY_KEY
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
rank INT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
```

`title_history`

```
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY_KEY
championship INT FOREIGN_KEY REFERENCES (championships.id)
winner VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
date_won DATE NOT NULL
```

I want to be able to pull the latest title holder. I can currently pull *a* title holder with the following MySQL `LEFT JOIN` query:

```
SELECT c.id, h.winner
FROM championships c
LEFT JOIN title_history h
ON c.id = h.championship
ORDER BY c.rank ASC
```

However, this just pulls the first result for each championship on a default index (`id` I presume). When I tried added `ORDER BY h.date_won` as a clause the query seems to fall over and return no results.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What does `championships.rank` stand for?

Comment: It's so I can order the championships in importance.

Comment: I dont realy get it if u want first for each championship then u should have some grouping not only left join, is this query u pasted here incomplete? Changing `order by` doesnt change number of rows u get so what did u exacly change  in this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've cracked it! The following query seems to give me what I need:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, h.winner
FROM championships c
LEFT JOIN title_history h
ON c.id = h.championship
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.rank ASC, h.date_from ASC
```

**EDIT:** I haven't cracked it. As I'm grouping by championship ID, I'm now only getting the *first* title winner, even if there have been title winners after.

**EDIT 2:** Solved with the following query:

```
SELECT friendly_name,
(SELECT winner FROM title_history WHERE championship = c.id ORDER BY date_from DESC LIMIT 1) 
FROM championships AS c
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `GROUP BY c.id` as `id` is the primary key of table `championships`.

Comment: if u group by c.Id ... how is it possible to use other columns, looks like incorect syntax

Comment: Syntactically "correct". But it makes baby database deity cry. :P

Comment: @djacobson: In some cases, it's perfectly valid syntax (when the other fields used or shown are dependent on the grouped fields). Baby cries because MySQL does no such check and allows whatever field one wants...

Answer (score 0):

This will show just the last (decided) championship:

```
SELECT winner
FROM title_history
ORDER BY date_won DESC
LIMIT 1
```

---

To show all championship and their winners, your `LEFT JOIN` attempt seems correct. Perhaps you want to order the results by `date_won`:

```
SELECT c.id, h.winner
FROM championships c
  LEFT JOIN title_history h
    ON c.id = h.championship
ORDER BY date_won DESC
```

---

or order by importance (and by date_won for championships with same importance):

```
SELECT c.id, h.winner
FROM championships c
  LEFT JOIN title_history h
    ON c.id = h.championship
ORDER BY c.rank ASC
       , h.date_won DESC
```

Comment: No, as I want the latest winner for each championship; but a championship may not have any winners even though I still want a result for that result, hence the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: This will not catch championships without winners (currently playing)

Comment: @Martin: I though you said *"I want the latest title holder"*

Comment: Sorry. I meant for each championship, as opposed to just the last champion to win a title.

Comment: @Martin: DO, you instead want all championships and their winners (and NULL for championships not decided yet)?